# CSS relative positioning and padding

Tags: css

After a couple of waisted hours I've managed to find a solution to my problem, so the question is not "how to", but "why it works like that". Here's my stripped down example:

```
<div id="header">
    <div id="header-element">header</div>
</div>
<div id="footer">footer</div>​
```

CSS:

```
#header {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 5%;
}
#header-element {
    position:absolute;
    bottom: 0;
}
#footer {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 5%;
}​
```

And jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/H7jwm/3/.

My problem was how to position those relatively positioned elements using percentage, first one some % off the top of the document, and the second one from the first one. I've accomplished that by giving `padding-bottom` to the first one, and `margin-top` to the second one, but I've got to the solution with a brute force - trying out every remotely logical solution. Now, if you remove the padding, `margin-top` of the second element becomes margin between that element and the top of the document, not the first element, and that first element "takes" rest of the space to the top.

The question is why that padding works like that? Or, to rephrase it, how does padding work with relative positioning?

Comment: I don't understand what is the other situation you managed to avoid. Another fiddle perhaps?

Comment: I managed to avoid not being able to put `#header` some % from the document top, and `#footer` some % from `#header`.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, you are mixing positions. Your `#header` has a height of zero. That's right, zero like in nothing, because it has no relative content. `#header-element` is absolutely positioned and because `#header` has a height of 0 it happens to be exactly in the padding-bottom space.

So, if you remove the padding-bottom from `#header`, the `#footer` moves up, starting right at the top of the document. Because of the margin-top, there's some space between the document top border and the word 'footer'.

But you still have that absolutely positioned `#header-element`, which will now be right in that margin-top space.

Comment: Yes, I know `#header` has a height of zero, but I don't understand how the 'padding-bottom' percentage is calculated here. Is it calculated from the height of the document (it doesn't seem that way), and the padding itself becomes the height of the `#header`?

Comment: Percentage values used with padding should always refer to the parent block element.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I thought so too and tested it with various percentage, but the results showed that is not the case (or I'm messing things up badly). If I'm not mistaken, `body` is a block element, and `#header` in my original project is a first level child of `body`.